# TestNG installation fails in eclipse Install New software

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

On trying to install the TestNG from eclipse Install New Software using the URL "http://beust.com/eclipse" throws some error which is attached in the screen shot below.I tried appending "/" after the eclipse in the URL. I also tried using https. I tried installing from the market place as well. But no luck!! Same error thrown.Somebody please help me.
[Test NG Installation error in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDzQF.png)

Comment: Do you see the same error while installing it from Market Place? Update the Market Place error snapshot.

Comment: Its the same error screen shot which is attached above.An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.testng.eclipse,6.11.0.201703011520
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.testng.eclipse,6.11.0.201703011520

Comment: dont use screenshopts for errors, just paste the text into your question

Comment: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.testng.eclipse,6.11.0.201703011520 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.testng.eclipse,6.11.0.2017030‌​11520

Comment: Similar issue already occurred: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/316

Comment: do you still see the same error if use the update site: http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse/.